# Why does my int not return properly?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

So, I've got a fairly straightforward method

```
byte[] mem;
int pc;

private int d16() {
    return (((int) this.mem[pc++]) | ((int) this.mem[pc++] << 8) & 0x00FFFF);
}
```

If I print the value before returning and the LSB (Little endian form) is `0xFF`, then I get `0xffcd` for example. However, if I print the return value AFTER the return (where I call the method) I get `0xffffffcd` .. Which is a very different value.

My soft solution is

```
int a = d16() & 0xFFFF;
```

But I shouldn't have to do that, I don't think.

### Question

Why does my bitmask not follow the return value through the return?

Comment: What's the type of `mem` array? And what values are in it?

Comment: @Eran that is a fantastic question and I have updated my question with this information. I'm storing opcodes (and other raw bytes) for an emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of operator precedence: `&` is of higher precedence than `|` according to [this precedence table for Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/).  Despite all the parentheses, there are no parentheses around the two OR (`|`) operands.  This means that this occurs first:

```
((int) this.mem[pc++] << 8) & 0x00FFFF
```

Then that value is OR'ed with the first value, `((int) this.mem[pc++])`.  When these values are cast to `int`, it is likely that sign extension is occurring here, *after* the bitmask is applied.  This can explain the `0xffffffcd` return value.

You will need to place parentheses around the `|` operands to ensure the OR happens first, then the AND with the bitmask will occur afterwards.

```
//       v                                                      v
return ( ( ((int) this.mem[pc++]) | ((int) this.mem[pc++] << 8) ) & 0x00FFFF);
```

Comment: Just to make myself feel better, I feel I must tell you I've been doing Java for about 7 years and have been doing bit-manipulation for 3... I guess this is just a brain fart syntax error.